# Change single keyframe value using expressions

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I'm making a preset for my video projects. It's a shape layer that takes dimensions from a text layer, so the text fits accurately in the shape.

For this, I'm doing the following:

Shape Layer > Contents > Box > Box shape (X, Y in pixels) >

```
width = thisComp.layer("Text").sourceRectAtTime().width;
height = thisComp.layer("Text").sourceRectAtTime().height;

[width, height]
```

Wich, as I said, it makes the text fit in the box. It works all fine here.
What I want to do is to animate the shape's dimensions (X and Y property, as said above) using keyframes instead of `linear()` or other expressions. I want to modify only one specified keyframe (in this case, the last one).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With my current understanding of how After Effects expressions work, I don't think that can be done.

According to user Mylenium in [this comment thread](https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/dynamic-keyframe-value-using-expression/m-p/10130410),

> Keyframe values are read-only